# How do I create a dynamic dropdown in a razor file using a public string class? I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, razor, drop-down-menu

In the example, Square is a public string within an entity as a {get;set;}. Area is being used in a razor.cs file as a Paramater that corresponds to the razor file. I'm not sure how to dynamically render the dropdown without getting this error. Also, it's supposed be a combobox but this was the code supplied by the docs

AreaLanding.razor

```
 <div class="col">
       <div class="m-3">
            <label for="single-choice" class="form-label">Service Area</label>
                 <select class="form-control" data-trigger name="single-choice"
                                id="single-choice" placeholder="Service Area Search>
                                @foreach (var option in Area.Square)
                                {
                                    <option value="@option">@option</option>
                                }
                 </select>
         </div>
    </div>
```

AreaLanding.razor.cs

```
namespace Something.Namespace.Area
{
    public partial class AreaLanding
    {
       
        private string SearchQuery = "";
        public List<AreaDocumentSearch> returnData = new List<AreaDocumentSearch>();

        [Parameter]
        public AreaDocumentSearch Area { get; set; }
```

AreaVector.razor.cs

```
 public class AreaDocumentSearch
    {
        public required string Id { get; set; }
        public string Square{ get; set; }
```

I've tried Area.Square as that has worked in other parts of the project. The @foreach above makes sense for a dropdown. In spite of that and not getting errors in VSCode, the page doesn't render.

```
<option value="@Area.Square">@Area.Square</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

```
@foreach (var option in Area.Square)
{
    <option value="@option">@option</option>
}
```

You can only `foreach` enumerables. `Area.Square` seems to be a `string`, which *is* in fact enumerable, but it will give you one character at a time, which I doubt you want.

```cs
public List<AreaDocumentSearch> returnData = new List<AreaDocumentSearch>();
```

Now that’s a proper `IEnumerable`. You probably want to iterate over this.

It kind of feels like you don’t have a firm grasp on what `foreach` does? [Try checking the official docs about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-foreach-statement), but I’m *guessing* what you want is something like this:

```
@foreach (var area in returnData)
{
    <option value="@area.Id">@area.Square</option>
}
```

However, I have no experience with razor components or blazor or whatever this is exactly, so I might be totally off.

> Also, it's supposed be a combobox

Unfortunately there is no combobox element in HTML. There are only javascript-powered abominations or this pathetic excuse: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Good luck!